# MSTest and TFS Build 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am having some issues trying to get my automated builds to compile projects that reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll. For some reason the project fails to compile complaining that

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.

I have installed VS2010 Premium on my build server but this does not seem to have resolved the issue. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version `Version=9.0.0.0` is part of VS2008, so it makes sense that it can't be found on your build server even though you 've installed VS2010.
Consider changing your project-ref into `Version=10.0.0.0` which corresponds to your current VS-version.

Comment: Perfect. This was indeed the issue. One of the test projects referenced the older version for some reason. Thanks!